# using imported sass file with render functions in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I have abstracted a vue render function into a separate javascript file. Now I want to add a sass component style to it. My present approach does not work. Is there a way to call scoped sass into a render function or a functional component? here is my code:

```
//form.js
import '../../assets/form.scss'
export default {
    render(createElement){
        return createElement('form',{
            class:{
            form:true
        },
            attrs: {
                class:'form'
            }
        }, [
            createElement('input',{attrs: {'placeholder':'Enter url'}}),
            createElement('button', 'Submit')
        ])
```

}
}

Comment: I really don't know how classes are being parsed in render functions. Are they being parsed from the parent component? What are styles does the 'class' property refer to?

Comment: If you're using SFC you can just add 'style' tag to compile scope scss/sass.

Comment: @TimothyLee, I don't really understand what you mean. Please could you explain further? Do you mean that I should write the sass code directly in a style attribute in this component or the main component that calls this one? Or do you mean something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I have to import `form.scss` in the parent component, I could also have done it this same way, for some reason it was not working earlier. The `attrs` attribute is not required.